# How to printout the sequence in ascending order when I use pre-order traversal to print

Tags: java

Here is my assignment

> run your program by inserting the sequence [2 7 9 4 1 5 3 6 0 8] and printout the sequence again in ascending order

```
      import java.util.*;
class TestBinary {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        BinarySearch tree = new BinarySearch();

        tree.root = new BinaryNode(1);
        tree.root.left = new BinaryNode(4);
        tree.root.right = new BinaryNode(5);

        tree.root.left.left = new BinaryNode(7);
        tree.root.left.left.left = new BinaryNode(2);
        tree.root.left.left.right = new BinaryNode(9);


        tree.root.right.right = new BinaryNode(6);
        tree.root.right.right.left = new BinaryNode(3);

        tree.root.right.right.right= new BinaryNode(8);
        tree.root.right.right.right.left = new BinaryNode(0);

        System.out.println("This is in-order traversal:");
        tree.inorder();
    }
}
```

The result is:
This is pre-order traversal:
2794153608
I want to printout it again in ascending order, how can I do?

Comment: use in-order instead of pre-order if you want ascending order

Comment: I don't know who can write it

Comment: If I use in order, the result print:7921435068

Comment: Well, that's because your tree is not a binary search tree. For example, the left child of 2 can't be 7.

Comment: The question in my homework is:run your program by inserting the sequence [2 7 9 4 1 5 3 6 0 8] and printout the sequence again in ascending order. Therefore I don't know it is pre-order or in-order

Comment: You have to maintain the invariant of binary search trees when adding the elements to the tree - all the elements of the left sub-tree must be smaller than the root and all the elements of the right sub-tree must be larger than the root.

Comment: Please delete the answer below and [edit] your question

Comment: If you have a `insertSubtree` method, you must use it to build the tree... As mentioned, your tree isn't a proper binary one because all left elements are not less than the right elements for a given node

Answer (score 1):

2 7 9 4 1 5 3 6 0 8

If you inserted a tree in that order, you should expect this tree

```
                    2
                   / \
                  1    7
                 /    / \
                0    4   9
                    / \   /
                   3   5 8
                       \
                        6
```

Notice that for any given node, all left elements are less than it, recursively, all right nodes are greater than it. If you build enough trees you'll also notice that this property will always be true, which is why in-order traversal should always output ascending order

The problem is your main method, not necessarily the tree class. As you're inserting data, you must iterate the tree and compare elements, not just pick and choose which node goes where, manual assigning fields.

Once you correctly insert the nodes, an inorder traversal will naturally print the data in ascending order, as mentioned

For example

```
BinarySearch tree = new BinarySearch();

int i = 0;
tree.root = new BinaryNode(data[i++]);
while(i < data.length) {
    tree.add(tree.root, data[i++]);
}
tree.inOrder();
```